# What is the exhaustive list of command line shortcuts to Microsoft settings?

Tags: command-line-interface, settings, shortcut

I've gotten quite used to typing `compmgnt.msc` or similar commands to bring up certain dialogs faster than it would take me to navigate to them. For this one in particular I just tap `Start` then `r` `enter` `c` `o` `down-arrow` `enter`. There's others I use too, but I wish there were a centralized compendium of commands for the  like this for the command line or `run...` field. At least for Windows Sever 2003. And it certainly would be nice if it were a brief but complete description in the table/list that was searchable or filterable.

Has anyone seen a list like this that you could link to in your answer? Perhaps with a sample in the answer of what it would describe `compmgngt.msc` as for `find` usage.

(Aside (not part of the question) by `find` I mean whatever you use to jump through a long webpage. For me it's Control-F, but I'm trying not to exclude people who'd use F3 or '/' or Alt-E-F or any method not called `find` etc etc. depending on your browser.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

EDIT:

I guess you meant keyboard shortcuts in general. The following is a list of Windows "run" commands. I'll keep this up for my own benefit.

from http://mypchell.com/content/view/69/1/:

```
Accessibility Controls                                       access.cpl
Accessibility Wizard                                         accwiz
Add Hardware Wizard                                          hdwwiz.cpl
Add/Remove Programs                                          appwiz.cpl
Administrative Tools                                         control admintools
Adobe Acrobat (if installed)                                 acrobat
Adobe Designer (if installed)                                acrodist
Adobe Distiller (if installed)                               acrodist
Adobe ImageReady (if installed)                              imageready
Adobe Photoshop (if installed)                               photoshop
Automatic Updates                                            wuaucpl.cpl
Bluetooth Transfer Wizard                                    fsquirt
Calculator                                                   calc
Certificate Manager                                          certmgr.msc
Character Map                                                charmap
Check Disk Utility                                           chkdsk
Clipboard Viewer                                             clipbrd
Command Prompt                                               cmd
Component Services                                           dcomcnfg
Computer Management                                          compmgmt.msc
Control Panel                                                control
Date and Time Properties                                     timedate.cpl
DDE Shares                                                   ddeshare
Device Manager                                               devmgmt.msc
Direct X Control Panel (If Installed)*                       directx.cpl
Direct X Troubleshooter                                      dxdiag
Disk Cleanup Utility                                         cleanmgr
Disk Defragment                                              dfrg.msc
Disk Management                                              diskmgmt.msc
Disk Partition Manager                                       diskpart
Display Properties (w/Appearance Tab Preselected)            control color
Display Properties                                           control desktop
Display Properties                                           desk.cpl
Dr. Watson System Troubleshooting Utility                    drwtsn32
Driver Verifier Utility                                      verifier
Event Viewer                                                 eventvwr.msc
File Signature Verification Tool                             sigverif
Files and Settings Transfer Tool                             migwiz
Findfast                                                     findfast.cpl
Firefox (if installed)                                       firefox
Folders Properties                                           control folders
Fonts Folder                                                 fonts
Fonts                                                        control fonts
Free Cell Card Game                                          freecell
Game Controllers                                             joy.cpl
Group Policy Editor (XP Prof)                                gpedit.msc
Hearts Card Game                                             mshearts
Help and Support                                             helpctr
HyperTerminal                                                hypertrm
Iexpress Wizard                                              iexpress
Indexing Service                                             ciadv.msc
Internet Connection Wizard                                   icwconn1
Internet Explorer                                            iexplore
Internet Properties                                          inetcpl.cpl
Internet Setup Wizard                                        inetwiz
IP Configuration (Delete DNS Cache Contents)                 ipconfig /flushdns
IP Configuration (Display Connection Configuration)          ipconfig /all
IP Configuration (Display DHCP Class ID)                     ipconfig /showclassid
IP Configuration (Display DNS Cache Contents)                ipconfig /displaydns
IP Configuration (Modifies DHCP Class ID)                    ipconfig /setclassid
IP Configuration (Refreshes DHCP & Re-Registers DNS)         ipconfig /registerdns
IP Configuration (Release All Connections)                   ipconfig /release
IP Configuration (Renew All Connections)                     ipconfig /renew
Java Control Panel (If Installed)                            javaws
Java Control Panel (If Installed)                            jpicpl32.cpl
Keyboard Properties                                          control keyboard
Local Security Settings                                      secpol.msc
Local Users and Groups                                       lusrmgr.msc
Logs You Out Of Windows                                      logoff
Malicious Software Removal Tool                              mrt
Microsoft Access (if installed)                              access.cpl
Microsoft Chat                                               winchat
Microsoft Excel (if installed)                               excel
Microsoft Frontpage (if installed)                           frontpg
Microsoft Movie Maker                                        moviemk
Microsoft Paint                                              mspaint
Microsoft Powerpoint (if installed)                          powerpnt
Microsoft Syncronization Tool                                mobsync
Microsoft Word (if installed)                                winword
Minesweeper Game                                             winmine
Mouse Properties                                             control mouse
Mouse Properties                                             main.cpl
Nero (if installed)                                          nero
Netmeeting                                                   conf
Network Connections                                          control netconnections
Network Connections                                          ncpa.cpl
Network Setup Wizard                                         netsetup.cpl
Notepad                                                      notepad
Nview Desktop Manager (If Installed)                         nvtuicpl.cpl
Object Packager                                              packager
ODBC Data Source Administrator                               odbccp32.cpl
On Screen Keyboard                                           osk
Opens AC3 Filter (If Installed)                              ac3filter.cpl
Outlook Express                                              msimn
Paint                                                        pbrush
Password Properties                                          password.cpl
Performance Monitor                                          perfmon
Performance Monitor                                          perfmon.msc
Phone and Modem Options                                      telephon.cpl
Phone Dialer                                                 dialer
Pinball Game                                                 pinball
Power Configuration                                          powercfg.cpl
Printers and Faxes                                           control printers
Printers Folder                                              printers
Private Character Editor                                     eudcedit
Quicktime (If Installed)                                     QuickTime.cpl
Quicktime Player (if installed)                              quicktimeplayer
Real Player (if installed)                                   realplay
Regional Settings                                            intl.cpl
Registry Editor                                              regedit
Registry Editor                                              regedit32
Remote Access Phonebook                                      rasphone
Remote Desktop                                               mstsc
Removable Storage Operator Requests                          ntmsoprq.msc
Removable Storage                                            ntmsmgr.msc
Resultant Set of Policy (XP Prof)                            rsop.msc
Scanners and Cameras                                         sticpl.cpl
Scheduled Tasks                                              control schedtasks
Security Center                                              wscui.cpl
Services                                                     services.msc
Shared Folders                                               fsmgmt.msc
Shuts Down Windows                                           shutdown
Sounds and Audio                                             mmsys.cpl
Spider Solitare Card Game                                    spider
SQL Client Configuration                                     cliconfg
System Configuration Editor                                  sysedit
System Configuration Utility                                 msconfig
System File Checker Utility (Purge File Cache)               sfc /purgecache
System File Checker Utility (Return to Default Setting)      sfc /revert
System File Checker Utility (Scan Immediately)               sfc /scannow
System File Checker Utility (Scan On Every Boot)             sfc /scanboot
System File Checker Utility (Scan Once At Next Boot)         sfc /scanonce
System File Checker Utility (Set Cache Size to size x)       sfc /cachesize=x
System Information                                           msinfo32
System Properties                                            sysdm.cpl
Task Manager                                                 taskmgr
TCP Tester                                                   tcptest
Telnet Client                                                telnet
Tweak UI (if installed)                                      tweakui
User Account Management                                      nusrmgr.cpl
Utility Manager                                              utilman
Windows Address Book Import Utility                          wabmig
Windows Address Book                                         wab
Windows Backup Utility (if installed)                        ntbackup
Windows Explorer                                             explorer
Windows Firewall                                             firewall.cpl
Windows Magnifier                                            magnify
Windows Management Infrastructure                            wmimgmt.msc
Windows Media Player                                         wmplayer
Windows Messenger                                            msmsgs
Windows Picture Import Wizard (need camera connected)        wiaacmgr
Windows System Security Tool                                 syskey
Windows Update Launches                                      wupdmgr
Windows Version (to show which version of windows)           winver
Windows XP Tour Wizard                                       tourstart
Wordpad                                                      write
```

Comment: Actually I meant only shortcuts for the run field, so this list is awesome. I wonder if it's complete. Some of the  descriptions are terse though (E.G. Fastfind => Fastfind.cpl). I will try to clarify that I wasn't talking about keyboard shortcuts in the question.

Answer (score 5):

This is a list I pulled from somewhere a few years back and have used ever since

```
ADFS.msc AD Federation Services 
CERTMGR.msc Certificate Management –Current User 
CERTSRV.msc Certification Authority 
CERTTMPL.msc Certificate Templates 
COMPMGMT.msc Computer Management 
COMEXP.msc Component Services  C:\windows\system32\com 
DCOMCNFG  Component Services 
DSA.msc  ADUC (AD Users and Computers) 
DFSGUI.msc DFS Management 
DFSMGMT.msc DFS Management R2 
DNSMGMT.msc   DNS Management 
DOMAIN.msc Domains and Trusts 
DSSITE.msc Sites and Services 
EVENTVWR.msc Event Viewer 
GPEDIT.msc Local Policy 
GPMC.msc   Group Policy Management Console 
PKIVIEW.msc PKI management 
RSOP.msc Resultant set of Policy 
SECPOL.msc Local Security Policy 
SERVICES.msc Services 
SCHMMGMT.msc    Schema Management 
TASKMGR Task Manager 
TSCC.msc  TS Configuration 

These are .exe’s


TSADMIN TS Administrator 
LICMGR TS Licensing 

The following are contained within the WINDOWS 2003 ADMINISTRATION TOOLS PACK
*Installed from the Windows Server 2003 CD

ADMGMT.msc AD Management –Domains, Sites, DNS and ADUC 
PKMGMT.msc PKI Management – Authorities, Templates 
IPADDRMGMT.msc WINS,DNS and DHCP in one console 

2008 SERVER


SERVERMANAGER.msc Server Manager 
NAPCLCFG.msc Network Access Protection Client Configuration 
STOREXPL.msc Storage Manager 
TSCONFIG TS Configuration 
WBADMIN Windows Server Backup 
WF.msc Windows Firewall + Advanced Security 

RUN shortcuts for Windows OS management


NCPA.CPL  Network Properties 
APPWIZ.CPL Add remove programs 
DEVMGMT.msc Device Manager 
FSMGMT.msc File Share Management 
SYSDM.CPL System Properties 
FIREWALL.CPL Firewall applet 
DESK.CPL Display Properties 
CONTROL Control Panel 
SYSDM.CPL System Properties         
ACCESS.CPL  Accessibility Options           
APPWIZ.CPL Add/Remove Programs             
TIMEDATE.CPL Date/Time Properties 
DESK.CPL           Display Properties   
FINDFAST.CPL            FindFast                        
FONTS  Fonts Folder       
INETCPL.CPL  Internet Properties             
JOY.CPL  Joystick Properties 
LUSRMGR.MSC Local Users and Groups             
MAIN.CPL Keyboard  Keyboard Properties      
MLCFG32.CPL  Microsoft Exchange    
WGPOCPL.CPL  Microsoft Mail Post Office         
MAIN.CPL  Mouse Properties                
MMSYS.CPL  Multimedia Properties           
PASWORD.CPL Password Properties             
MAIN.CPL PC CARD (pcmcia)                          PC Card  
PRINTERS  Printers Folder                 
INTL.CPL  Regional Settings               
STICPL.CPL  Scanners and Cameras            
MMSYS.CPL sounds Sound Properties                




Accessibility Controls - access.cpl 
Add Hardware Wizard - hdwwiz.cpl 
Add/Remove Programs - appwiz.cpl 
Administrative Tools - control admintools 
Automatic Updates - wuaucpl.cpl 
Bluetooth Transfer Wizard - fsquirt 
Calculator - calc 
Certificate Manager - certmgr.msc 
Character Map - charmap 
Check Disk Utility - chkdsk 
Clipboard Viewer - clipbrd 
Command Prompt - cmd 
Component Services - dcomcnfg 
Computer Management - compmgmt.msc 
Date and Time Properties - timedate.cpl 
DDE Shares - ddeshare 
Device Manager - devmgmt.msc 
Direct X Control Panel (If Installed)* - directx.cpl 
Direct X Troubleshooter - dxdiag 
Disk Cleanup Utility - cleanmgr 
Disk Defragment - dfrg.msc 
Disk Management - diskmgmt.msc 
Disk Partition Manager - diskpart 
Display Properties - control desktop 
Display Properties - desk.cpl 
Display Properties (w/Appearance Tab Preselected) - control color 
Dr. Watson System Troubleshooting Utility - drwtsn32 
Driver Verifier Utility - verifier 
Event Viewer - eventvwr.msc 
File Signature Verification Tool - sigverif 
Findfast - findfast.cpl 
Folders Properties - control folders 
Fonts - control fonts 
Fonts Folder - fonts 
Free Cell Card Game - freecell 
Game Controllers - joy.cpl 
Group Policy Editor (XP Prof) - gpedit.msc 
Hearts Card Game - mshearts 
Iexpress Wizard - iexpress 
Indexing Service - ciadv.msc 
Internet Properties - inetcpl.cpl 
IP Configuration (Display Connection Configuration) - ipconfig /all 
IP Configuration (Display DNS Cache Contents) - ipconfig /displaydns 
IP Configuration (Delete DNS Cache Contents) - ipconfig /flushdns 
IP Configuration (Release All Connections) - ipconfig /release 
IP Configuration (Renew All Connections) - ipconfig /renew 
IP Configuration (Refreshes DHCP & Re - Registers DNS) - 
ipconfig /registerdns 
IP Configuration (Display DHCP Class ID) - ipconfig /showclassid 
IP Configuration (Modifies DHCP Class ID) - ipconfig /setclassid 
Java Control Panel (If Installed) - jpicpl32.cpl 
Java Control Panel (If Installed) - javaws 
Keyboard Properties - control keyboard 
Local Security Settings - secpol.msc 
Local Users and Groups - lusrmgr.msc 
Logs You Out Of Windows - logoff 
Microsoft Chat - winchat 
Minesweeper Game - winmine 
Mouse Properties - control mouse 
Mouse Properties - main.cpl 
Network Connections - control netconnections 
Network Connections - ncpa.cpl 
Network Setup Wizard - netsetup.cpl 
Notepad - notepad 
Nview Desktop Manager (If Installed) - nvtuicpl.cpl 
Object Packager - packager 
ODBC Data Source Administrator - odbccp32.cpl 
On Screen Keyboard - osk 
Opens AC3 Filter (If Installed) - ac3filter.cpl 
Password Properties - password.cpl 
Performance Monitor - perfmon.msc 
Performance Monitor - perfmon 
Phone and Modem Options - telephon.cpl 
Power Configuration - powercfg.cpl 
Printers and Faxes - control printers 
Printers Folder - printers 
Private Character Editor - eudcedit 
Quicktime (If Installed) - QuickTime.cpl 
Regional Settings - intl.cpl 
Registry Editor - regedit 
Registry Editor - regedt32 
Remote Desktop - mstsc 
Removable Storage - ntmsmgr.msc 
Removable Storage Operator Requests - ntmsoprq.msc 
Resultant Set of Policy (XP Prof) - rsop.msc 
Scanners and Cameras - sticpl.cpl 
Scheduled Tasks - control schedtasks 
Security Center - wscui.cpl 
Services - services.msc 
Shared Folders - fsmgmt.msc 
Shuts Down Windows - shutdown 
Sounds and Audio - mmsys.cpl 
Spider Solitare Card Game - spider 
SQL Client Configuration - cliconfg 
System Configuration Editor - sysedit 
System Configuration Utility - msconfig 
System File Checker Utility (Scan Immediately) - sfc /scannow 
System File Checker Utility (Scan Once At Next Boot) - sfc /scanonce 
System File Checker Utility (Scan On Every Boot) - sfc /scanboot 
System File Checker Utility (Return to Default Setting) - sfc /revert 
System File Checker Utility (Purge File Cache) - sfc /purgecache 
System File Checker Utility (Set Cache Size to size x) - 
sfc /cachesize=x 
System Properties - sysdm.cpl 
Task Manager - taskmgr 
Telnet Client - telnet 
User Account Management - nusrmgr.cpl 
Utility Manager - utilman 
Windows Firewall - firewall.cpl 
Windows Magnifier - magnify 
Windows Management Infrastructure - wmimgmt.msc 
Windows System Security Tool - syskey 
Windows Update Launches - wupdmgr 
Windows XP Tour Wizard - tourstart 
Wordpad - write
```